# What is the order of the arguments in Python statsmodels cross-correlation function?

Tags: python, statistics, statsmodels, cross-correlation

I was looking at the documentation for the Python `statsmodels` cross-correlation function `statsmodels.tsa.stattools.ccf` and have a question.

**Question:** What is the order of the arguments into this function? So if we input `ccf(x, y)`, which one will the positive time lag correspond to:

(1) x(t)y(t + lag), OR

(2) y(t)x(t + lag)

It doesn't seem to be clear from the documentation https://www.statsmodels.org/stable/generated/statsmodels.tsa.stattools.ccf.html.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

This is how the `ccf` function is defined ([here](https://github.com/statsmodels/statsmodels/blob/master/statsmodels/tsa/stattools.py#L1137) you can have a look at the documentation):

```
x = array_like(x, "x")
y = array_like(y, "y")
adjusted = bool_like(adjusted, "adjusted")

cvf = ccovf(x, y, adjusted=adjusted, demean=True)
return cvf / (np.std(x) * np.std(y))
```

And [here](https://github.com/statsmodels/statsmodels/blob/87756b1730d78dffb21b6f2fc3cca8becf5b367e/statsmodels/tsa/stattools.py#L1093) the crosscovariance function (ccovf) definition too.

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply. Looking at the documentation, it looks like the `ccovf` function depends on `np.correlate`. According to this post here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37093382/interpreting-and-comparing-output-from-numpy-correlate, it looks as if the order of (x, y) corresponds to x(t)*y(t+lag). Does that seem correct? Many thanks

Comment: Yes, this is what I understood too